# When sharing in Facebook, different link than sharing from website

Tags: facebook, url, share, feed

I am using the `URL` feed dialog version for sharing from my own newsfeed.
When Sharing this from the website, i don't have any issue, it uses the correct picture and correct title and content.

Once posted to Facebook and then trying to share in facebook itself, it is not using the picture or title or content.

You can find an example here

http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/?page=news&newsid=32

This is the link with details being filled with PHP

```
        echo '      </br><div class="center"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145350652325572&name='.$rij_news['titel'].'&display=popup&caption='.$rij_news['message'].'&link=http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/?page=news%26newsid='.$_GET['newsid'].'&redirect_uri=http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/?page=news%26newsid='.$_GET['newsid'].'&picture=http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/news/'.$rij_news['newsThumb'].'" ><img src="img/sharebutton.png" width="100px" /></a></div>';
```

Am I using the wrong way for sharing the content from my site?

Comment: When content is re-shared on Facebook, it uses the Open Graph meta information of the URL, or extract the info itself if there is none. So if you want to have a particular title, description, image, you will have to implement Open Graph meta information in your page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Is there some example on how i can create my page with the correct meta tags? you put your metatags in your header tags, but the newsitem is just a part of the page that is being reloaded, so i'm not seeing how i can change my metatag for every page. Is there an online example that i can see on how this is handled, i probably are creating my pages in the wrong way i guess, but i can't find a good example to work with.

Comment: I tried to create meta tags by PHP, so now in my header when i open the page with the newsitem, the meta tags are loaded in the header section. Still when Re-sharing it is not using this data.

Comment: You still haven’t added og:title and og:description. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nwheelsandheels.be%2F%3Fpage%3Dnews%26newsid%3D32

Comment: Ok got it working now, totally forgot about that debugger, only one issue left, it is also showing my HTML tags that are used in the description, on my webpage it does not show these but in the link when sharing it does, is there a way to work arounf that? Already Many thanks for your super great help!!!

Comment: Well if you don’t want those HTML “tags” to show – then don’t put them in there …